# Node: serialport: Error: Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, arduino, node-serialport

I'm trying the [serialport package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) to communicate with an Arduino, but I can't seem to resolve an error that I'm having with my install of serialport.

I am running Windows 11 (21H2 22000.194)

**Error log:**

```
C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:135
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\default\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\compiled\14.17.6\win32\x64\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\release\install-root\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\debug\install-root\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\default\install-root\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\binding\node-v83-win32-x64\bindings.node
    at bindings (C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\win32.js:1:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\redacted\redacted\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\index.js:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14) {
  tries: [
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\build\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\build\\Debug\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\build\\Release\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\out\\Debug\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\Debug\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\out\\Release\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\Release\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\build\\default\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\compiled\\14.17.6\\win32\\x64\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\addon-build\\release\\install-root\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\addon-build\\debug\\install-root\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\addon-build\\default\\install-root\\bindings.node',
    'C:\\Users\\redacted\\redacted\\node_modules\\@serialport\\bindings\\lib\\binding\\node-v83-win32-x64\\bindings.node'
  ]
}
```

**So far I've tried:**

1. Using nvm to switch to the long term supported version of Node.js (v14.17.6)
2. Reinstalling the build tools through the Visual Studio installer
3. Reinstalling Python
4. Reinstalling the module several times

I just can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas that I could try?

Comment: Have you read: https://serialport.io/docs/guide-installation#compilation-problems ?